# chroot error: "failed to run command ‘PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin’: No such file or directory"

Tags: chroot, debian-jessie

I have created a Debian Jessie container using debootstrap, then I created a script to chroot into it. This is the script I use:

```
mount -t proc proc /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/proc/
mount -t sysfs sys /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/sys/
mount -o bind /dev /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/dev/
mount -o bind /dev /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/dev/pts
#mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf /home/matrix1/linuxrootdir/etc/resolv.conf

chroot /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir \
      PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin \

echo "Exiting chroot"
umount /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/dev/
umount /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/dev/pts
umount /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/sys/
umount /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/proc/
#umount /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir/etc/resolv.conf
```

The problem is that when I run it I get the following error:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin’: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out where the problem is, can somebody help me? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: if it could help. I am running Fedora 23 on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, you need

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin chroot /home/matrix1/LuMi/linuxrootdir
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your reply! You mean I should add this line to the script?

Comment: Anyway I replaced my chroot lines with your and it works now, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.  Please "Accept" the answer.  Thanks.